# Inserting a record to Recursive Table with EF Core 6, identity table set ON

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I have the following two tables

```
CREATE TABLE [Finance].[Account]
(
    [AccountId] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(100)  NOT NULL,    
    [AvailableBalance] DECIMAL(13, 4) NULL, 
    [CurrentBalance] DECIMAL(13, 4) NOT NULL, 
    [TypeId] INT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Account_Id] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AccountId] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY], 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Account_Type] 
        FOREIGN KEY (TypeId) REFERENCES [Finance].[AccountType](AccountTypeId)
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [Finance].[AccountType]
(
    [AccountTypeId] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [AccountTypeParentId] INT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL

    CONSTRAINT [PK_AccountType] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AccountTypeId])
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY], 
        CONSTRAINT [FK_AccountType_Parent_AccountType] 
            FOREIGN KEY (AccountTypeParentId) REFERENCES [Finance].[AccountType](AccountTypeId), 
   ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

With the following class structure

```
public class Account 
{
    public int AccountId { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public decimal AvailableBalance { get; private set; }
    public decimal CurrentBalance { get; private set; }
    public AccountType Type { get; private set; }
    
    public void SetType(AccountType type)
    {
        if (type != null)
        {
            Type = type;
        }
    }
}

public class AccountType 
{
    public int AccountTypeId { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int? AccountTypeParentId { get; private set; } = null;
    public AccountType ParentType { get; private set; }

    protected AccountType()
    {
    }

    private AccountType(int accountTypeId, string name) 
    {
        AccountTypeId = accountTypeId;
        Name = name;
    }

    public static AccountType CreateAccountType(string name)
    { 
        return new AccountType(0, name, DateTime.UtcNow);
    }

    public void SetParent(AccountType type)
    {
        ParentType = type;
    }
}
```

I am using following mapping in EF Core 6

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AccountType>(entity =>
{
    entity.ToTable("AccountType", schema: "Finance").HasKey(c=>c.AccountTypeId);
    entity.Property(c => c.AccountTypeId).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    entity.Property(t => t.AccountTypeId).HasColumnName("AccountTypeId");
    entity.Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("Name");
    entity.Property(t => t.AccountTypeParentId).HasColumnName("AccountTypeParentId");
    entity.HasOne(t => t.ParentType)
       .WithMany()
       .HasForeignKey("AccountTypeParentId");       
});

modelBuilder.Entity<Account>(entity =>
{
    entity.ToTable("Account", schema: "Finance");
    entity.Property(c => c.AccountId).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    entity.Property(o => o.CurrentBalance).HasColumnType("decimal(13,4)");
    entity.Property(o => o.AvailableBalance).HasColumnType("decimal(13,4)");
    entity.HasOne(b => b.Type).WithOne().HasForeignKey<AccountType>(b => b.AccountTypeId);
});
```

When trying to insert a record using the following call

```
Account account = CreateAccount();
AccountType type = AccountType.CreateAccountType("ParentType");
type.SetParent(AccountType.CreateAccountType("ChildType"));
account.SetType(type);

_context.Accounts.Add(account);
```

I am getting the following exception

> SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'AccountType' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

It seems like everything is set right, I am new to EF Core, so not sure how it handles recursive insert.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you really using a prerelease version of EF Core 7?

Comment: See : https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/27541338/identity-insert-is-set-to-off---visual-studio

Comment: Are you sure you want to "create" an account type and parent account type?? This seems more like you'd be referencing existing account types or at least parent account types on a new account. If your "CreateAccountType" method is doing something like a "create if not exists" you will want to make sure that the created or existing account types are tracked by the DbContext and not detached. When dealing with new entities using Identity columns you don't want to set IDs, the convention should be treating them as identity columns and will insert new rows if new/untracked entities are added.

Comment: You would also want to you `.DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)` rather than `.ValueGeneratedOnAdd()` for Identity columns.

Comment: @DavidG I think I was wrong it Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore -Version 6.0.7

Comment: @StevePy I tried .DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity) no luck

Comment: A 1:1 association between Account and AccountType seems unlikely. Everything runs OK if you change it to `entity.HasOne(b => b.Type).WithMany()`.

Comment: Good spot Gert, yeah that HasOne.WithOne would be trying to marry the PKs between the two tables leading to trying to insert into an Identity column. It should definitely be HasOne.WithMany().